# JBoss EAP is up and running but isn't accessible through web browser

Tags: jboss, jboss6.x, jboss-eap-7

I am running a deployed application on localhost and accessing it from browser but not able to access it on browser though 8080 is listening.

Sometime it is showing "Refused to connect" or "Webpages not found"

This is my **standalone.xml**

```
<interfaces>
        <interface name="management">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.management:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="public">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
        <interface name="unsecure">
            <inet-address value="${jboss.bind.address.unsecure:0.0.0.0}"/>
        </interface>
    </interfaces>

    <socket-binding-group name="standard-sockets" default-interface="public" port-offset="${jboss.socket.binding.port-offset:0}">
        <socket-binding name="management-native" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.native.port:9999}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-http" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.http.port:9990}"/>
        <socket-binding name="management-https" interface="management" port="${jboss.management.https.port:9443}"/>
        <socket-binding name="ajp" port="8009"/>
        <socket-binding name="http" port="8080"/>
        <socket-binding name="https" port="8443"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb" interface="unsecure" port="3528"/>
        <socket-binding name="jacorb-ssl" interface="unsecure" port="3529"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging" port="5445"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-group" port="0" multicast-address="${jboss.messaging.group.address:231.7.7.7}" multicast-port="${jboss.messaging.group.port:9876}"/>
        <socket-binding name="messaging-throughput" port="5455"/>
        <socket-binding name="remoting" port="4447"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-recovery-environment" port="4712"/>
        <socket-binding name="txn-status-manager" port="4713"/>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="mail-smtp">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="25"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
        <outbound-socket-binding name="remote-ejb-connection1">
            <remote-destination host="localhost" port="4689"/>
        </outbound-socket-binding>
    </socket-binding-group>

    <deployments>
        <deployment name="ace-ear-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT.ear" runtime-name="ace-ear-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT.ear">
            <content sha1="213bc2a0282e8488d75711d9c49fbdb2c607e84b"/>
        </deployment>
        <deployment name="ace-admin-ear-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT-LOCAL.ear" runtime-name="ace-admin-ear-1.0.11-SNAPSHOT-LOCAL.ear">
            <content sha1="d609bf2cc5284b06229579c64eed2570ebc3b7ca"/>
        </deployment>
    </deployments>
```

Comment: It does look to be bound to `http-/127.0.0.1:8080` so you should be able to access that in your browser.  That will get you to the admin console.  If that works, then I'd worry about how to get to your deployed applications URL.  You can also try to telnet to 127.0.0.1 8080.  Connection refused would only occur if JBoss is not bound to that IP address and port.  Also ensure you're not trying to use https on port 8080

Comment: @JGlass I am not hitting URL with https and 808 port showing listening when I do telnet . So I am so confused what else is causing this problem.

Comment: Did you make any modifications at all to the config file?  If you can telnet to the port I doubt its a firewall issue.  When you start JBoss, how are you starting it, from the command line through standalone.sh or standalone.bat?  Are you passing any arguments to the script when starting?  Do you have a coworker that you could zip up the JBoss folder, give it to them and have them try and run it to see if it works?  If it doesnt work for them, I'd re-download JBoss and try with a "fresh", unmodified version and see if it works, then add in any changes you might have made.

Comment: What's the URL that you are trying to access?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As you have mentioned sometimes you were getting "Refused to connect" or "Webpages not found", can you clarify is it working most of the times and sometimes you were getting this error or every time?

Can you check in your server log 8080 port is listening on your configured IP? for eg:

> > INFO  [org.wildfly.extension.undertow] (MSC service thread 1-1) WFLYUT0006: Undertow HTTP listener http listening on 127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: There are two lines in log

Comment: 01:47:03,662 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003001: Coyote HTTP/1.1 initializing on : http-/127.0.0.1:8080
01:47:03,786 INFO  [org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Protocol] (MSC service thread 1-6) JBWEB003000: Coyote HTTP/1.1 starting on: http-/127.0.0.1:8080

Comment: Is this specific to any browser?What error is reflected in logs when you get Refused Connection on Browser intermittently?

Comment: Nope. It is not browser specific, It's an error on each browser. Log doesn't print anything.